# Installed Windows 10 first, can I dual boot 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, 17.10, windows-10

Many tutorials talk about disabling secure boot before installing 17.10 over Windows 10. Sadly, I **have already put 17.10 alongside** an already installed Windows 10 (based on dual boot experience of Windows 7 days). I even **tried EasyBCD, which shows greyed out entry when I try to add Ubuntu** to boot.

Currently, the PC boots into Windows 10 as if there is no Ubuntu installed on it. Is it possible to fix this ? Please tell me how.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have already installed 17.10. What should I do now ?

Comment: There's a "Troubleshooting" section at the end of the top answer to the linked question, try the stuff there.